# Haskell: Rigid type variable error

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, monads

I have those info on my haskell code:

```
data Symtable a = General a | Stack a

class Evaluable e where
eval :: (Num a, Ord a) => (Ident -> Maybe a) -> (e a) -> (Either String a)
typeCheck :: (Ident -> String) -> (e a) -> Bool

instance (Num a, Ord a) => Evaluable (NExpr a) where
eval _ (Const n) = Right n
typeCheck f f2 = True --to make the code compilable
```

it gives me an error on the definition of eval because it says: couldn't match type 'e' with NExpr' 'e' is a rigid type variable bound by ... eval::... expected e a actual Nexpr a

ident = string and Nexpr:

```
data NExpr n = Const n |
            Var Ident |
            Plus (NExpr n) (NExpr n) |
            Minus (NExpr n) (NExpr n) |
            Times (NExpr n) (NExpr n)
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Change the instance to `instance (Num a, Ord a) => Evaluable NExpr  where ...`

Comment: then it says:
Expecting one more argument to Nexpr the first argument of Evaluable should have kind * but has kind * -> * @Alec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code block that you gave is really exactly what you've got in your file, then you got your indentation wrong. After fixing the indentation, and following the hint of Alec regarding the instance definition, this type-checks:

```
type Ident = String

data NExpr n = Const n |
            Var Ident |
            Plus (NExpr n) (NExpr n) |
            Minus (NExpr n) (NExpr n) |
            Times (NExpr n) (NExpr n)

data Symtable a = General a | Stack a

class Evaluable e where
  eval :: (Num a, Ord a) => (Ident -> Maybe a) -> e a -> Either String a
  typeCheck :: (Ident -> String) -> e a -> Bool

instance Evaluable NExpr where
  eval _ (Const n) = Right n
  typeCheck f f2 = True --to make the code compilable
```

Note that the definitions after `where` need to be indented.

The way you wrote it, you are defining a method outside of any class or instance:

```
eval :: (Num a, Ord a) => (Ident -> Maybe a) -> e a -> Either String a
eval _ (Const n) = Right n
```

But in this case `eval`'s type specifies that it must be defined for *all* `e a`, not just for `NExpr a`.

Comment: it was a problem with indentation